# Dynamically adding li in ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul class="name-email-list">
      <li>xxxx<strong> tttttt</strong><a href="#." class="icon-close"></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: If you want us to provide in-depth solutions to your problems you should do your part and write a decent question as well. This is a give-take community. People will start ignoring your questions if you don't reward correct answers (p.s. you get some reputation points as well). Your questions will also get closed quickly if you write poor questions like this one. But since you're new to Stackoverflow community (2 days so far) this is just **a warm welcome suggestion**. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### .appendTo()

[jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)
First get your content and append it to some element:

```
$("<li>WhateverContent</li>").appendTo(".name-email-list");
```

### .append()

[jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
First get some element and append it your content:

```
$(".name-email-list").append("<li>WhateverContent</li>");
```

As you can see either of them can be used. They work the opposite way. Use the one that's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.name-email-list').append('<li>New  li </li>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method:

```
$('ul.name-email-list').append('<li>xxxx<strong> tttttt</strong><a href="#." class="icon-close"></a></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function:

```
$('ul.name-email-list').append('<li>xxxx<strong> tttttt</strong><a href="#." class="icon-close"></a></li>');
```

But beware, that you need to reference your ul in a way, that only the targeted ul is selected. e.g. by ensuring, that only one ul has this class, or by giving the ul an id.